# How do you print returned values from multiple functions?

Tags: python, function, printing, return-value

I have a program that is for conversions of simple metrics. I'm a super noob to python and could use a little help.

```
def main():
    use_menu()
    if feet_inches():
        

def use_menu():
    get_menu()
    selection = int(input('Please make a menu selection:'))
    if selection == 1:
        feet_inches()
    elif selection == 2:
        yards_feet()
    elif selection == 3:
        miles_yards()
    elif selection == 4:
        miles_feet()


def get_menu():
    print('1. Convert feet to inches')
    print('2. Convert yards to feet')
    print('3. Convert miles to yards')
    print('4. Convert miles to feet')
    print('5. Exit')


def feet_inches():
    feet2inches = int(input('Enter the number of feet:'))
    answer1 = feet2inches / 3
    return answer1


def yards_feet():
    yards2feet = int(input('Enter the number of yards:'))
    answer2 = yards2feet * 3
    return answer2


def miles_yards():
    miles2yards = int(input('Enter the number of miles:'))
    answer3 = miles2yards * 1760
    return answer3


def miles_feet():
    miles2feet = int(input('Enter the number of miles:'))
    answer4 = miles2feet * 5280
    return answer4


main()
```

How do I print the returned values in my main function? I keep getting unresolved reference when I try to set answer1 to a variable in the main function. I'm also struggling with how to write the if/elif for that. Just a little nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3:

```
if feet_inches():
```

there is no conditional action underneath.

You could try something like this: Remove line 3 above.

```
def use_menu():
    get_menu()
    selection = int(input('Please make a menu selection:'))
    if selection == 1:
        fi = feet_inches()
        print(fi)
    elif selection == 2:
        yf = yards_feet()
        print(yf)
    elif selection == 3:
        my = miles_yards()
        print(my)
    elif selection == 4:
        mf = miles_feet()
        print(mf)
```

Comment: yes, this is the part I'm stuck at. When I try to set the returned value to a variable to print, I get unresolved reference.

Comment: I edited your code above, try it out, This should work for your needs.

Comment: This helped so much. If I didn't print the returned values in use_menu they are lost I guess, because I'm not returning them to my main function? Thank you for showing me what I was missing.

Comment: Wouldn't make more sense using one print statement at the end of the function, rather than having one for each if option? It is clear but repetitive.

Comment: It would, I agree, but as he is new to python, the easier to understand the better.

Comment: You're probably exactly right sir. I'm not sure if I follow how to simplify it that way though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use return statements in the `use_menu` aswell. And then set the answer equal to what is returned by that function in the main function.

```
def main():
    answer = use_menu()
    print(answer)


def use_menu():
    get_menu()
    selection = int(input('Please make a menu selection:'))
    if selection == 1:
        return feet_inches()
    elif selection == 2:
        return yards_feet()
    elif selection == 3:
        return miles_yards()
    elif selection == 4:
        return miles_feet()
```

Comment: this is a bit confusing, because by the name you wouldn't think that `use_menu` returns a value

Comment: I agree, but I dont want to change the original code too much. Just add a solution to his question.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code as follows:

```
def main():
    # First, retrieve function to be applied
    func = use_menu()
    if func is not None:
        # Apply function - Could be done in one liner
        res = func()
        print(res)
    

def use_menu():
    get_menu()
    selection = int(input('Please make a menu selection:'))
    if selection == 1:
        return feet_inches
    elif selection == 2:
        return yards_feet
    elif selection == 3:
        return miles_yards
    elif selection == 4:
        return miles_feet
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Between you and the other top answer it really helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Neekolie glad it has helped you